# Reading cookie in Velocity template

Tags: templates, liferay, liferay-6

Is it possible to read a cookie value in `portal_normal.vm` in Liferay 6.2?

Comment: You should only focus on one question at once. And you should check the differences between a short term _Query String_ and a long term _Cookie_. There is no _better_ as long as you don't know what you want to do.

Comment: I need to take id from prev web

Comment: Which _template.vm_ do you mean? _portal_normal.vm_? And please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: on general template that load the web, what is best practice to get param from url or from cookie, can you please add example how to take from cookie?

Comment: I still don't understand your question. You should check your wording: _web_ = [World Wide Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web). So you can't _load the web_. It is always good to provide an example to your question - that I can align my answer to that example.

Comment: I removed your second question - as this has nothing to do with the title or the first question or is a Liferay specific question at all. You can create it as new question - but please check that the question wasn't asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also do it using javaScript in portal_normal.vm

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Goto [javaScript cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the cookie access method from the request:

```
#set($previousWeb = "...")
#foreach($cookie in $request.getCookies())
    #if ($cookie.getName() eq "web")
        #set($previousWeb = $cookie.getValue())
    #end
#end
```

Comment: is it possible to ask cookie by id? without for?

Comment: Not from the request. There is a helper class `CookieKeys` - but that one is not available in a template (at least not out of the box) and it does nearly the same.

Comment: You can check what you have available by checking the interface. You can find out what $request actually is by temporary printing $request.getClass().getName()

Comment: @Olaf I agree to _checking the interface_ (would be `HttpServletRequest`). But not to `$request.getClass().getName()` - as this will print an implementation specific class.

Comment: I agree, Tobias - this gives the specific class. It's still a good place to start when looking for the interface and what it reveals. @VitalyMenchikovsky: Use your best judgement to find an API interface when you look at the class's javadoc or interface.